# What do I need to take into account if I want to test one model on different test datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

I'm just new to machine learning, I want to test a generative model on two different test datasets to compare its performance on different datasets. What do I need to take into account about the datasets? like should these two datasets have the same size?